# How to Integrate the tt_address contents in indexed search?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I am using TYPO3 7.6.9 and I want to integrate the tt_address contents in indexed search. If anyone has an idea then please give reply.

Comment: Have a look at xavier's guide for indexing http://xavier.perseguers.ch/en/tutorials/typo3/articles/indexed-search-crawler.html, It may help you.

Comment: I try with this but didn't got success.

Answer (score 0):

indexed_search indexes cached content of what it sees in the Frontend.
So if you have integrated a standard tt_address plugin on any page, please have a look in template setup if there is any occurance of a USER_INT object . If this is the case, change it to USER and then reindex the page.

HTH! Kind regards, MT

Comment: I dont use tt_address directly but i use wt_directory and use tt_address records to display wt_directory list.

Comment: wt_directory definitely creates a "USER_INT" by default - there is a somewhat dated forum entry on this: https://translate.google.de/translate?hl=de&sl=de&tl=en&u=https://www.typo3.net/forum/thematik/zeige/thema/109967/